# I am getting data from my database using Datatable, but it takes too much time to load

Tags: laravel, datatable, loading

I am getting data from products table, i have use paginate in datatable which shows only 50 records first time, and when pager update to 200 rows it takes 12 to 13sec. Here is my Code. Thanks in Advance

```
    $query = Product::query();
    $query->with('def_or_last_supplier','units','prouctImages','productType',
    'productBrand','productSubCategory',
    'supplier_products','productCategory')
    ->where('status',1)->orderBy('refrence_no', 'DESC');

    if($request->default_supplier != '')
    {
        $supplier_query = $request->default_supplier;
        $query = $query->whereIn('id', SupplierProducts::select('product_id')->where('supplier_id',$supplier_query)->pluck('product_id'));
    }

    if($request->prod_type != '')
    {
        $query->where('type_id', $request->prod_type)->where('status',1)->orderBy('refrence_no', 'DESC');
    }

    if($request->prod_category != '')
    {
        $query->where('category_id', $request->prod_category)->where('status',1)->orderBy('refrence_no', 'DESC');
    }

    if($request->filter != '')
    {
        if($request->filter == 'stock')
        {
            $query = $query->whereIn('id',WarehouseProduct::select('product_id')->where('current_quantity','>',0.005)->pluck('product_id'));
        }
        elseif($request->filter == 'reorder')
        {
            $query->where('min_stock','>',0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using foreign keys and indexes in your database? That's for sure the first place to start

Comment: No, i am not using indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't that big but I think maybe result data size is a bit big
so what you can do is:

**1:** in my experience is to try to `select` your relations fields too you can do that like so

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```php
Product::with('def_or_last_supplier',
    'units:id,created_at,updated_at', // Just add :field_1,field_2,another_field
    'prouctImages:id,field_1,field_2'
    ....
)
```

**2:** I suggest you to take advantage of `lazy loading`. if it's possible don't eager load all your relations at once load them where it's needed

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

`$products = Product::get()`

**In blade or somewhere in application**
under a special condition I need to access to my relation, I can easily do that by
`$products->load('my_relation_name')`

**3:** I see a lot of `orderyBy` clauses in your code, what you can do is to `index` the fields that are searchable or needs to be ordered. it can be done by adding `->index()` in your migration file

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-indexes)

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('refrence_no')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**4:** and finally you can always try to cache your queries to prevent unnecessary queries to database, this is how cache works

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache)

```php
$products = Cache::remember('cache_name', $how_long_in_seconds, function () {
    return Product::get();
});
```

And finally here is the eloquent way of your query

```php
$query = \Cache::remember(json_encode($request->toArray()), 300, function () use ($request) {
    return Product::with('def_or_last_supplier',
        'units',
        'prouctImages',
        'productType',
        'productBrand',
        'productSubCategory',
        'supplier_products',
        'productCategory'
    )
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->orderByDesc('refrence_no')
        ->when($request->filled('default_supplier'),  function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $productIds = SupplierProducts::select('product_id')->where('supplier_id', $request->input('default_supplier'))->pluck('product_id');
            $query->whereIn('id', $productIds);
        })->when($request->filled('prod_type'),  function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('type_id', $request->input('prod_type'))->where('status', 1)->orderByDesc('refrence_no');
        })->when($request->filled('prod_category'),  function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category_id', $request->input('prod_category'))->where('status', 1)->orderByDesc('refrence_no');
        })->when($request->filled('filter'),  function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->when('stock' === $request->input('filter'),  function (Builder $query) {
                $query->whereIn('id', WarehouseProduct::select('product_id')->where('current_quantity', '>', 0.005)->pluck('product_id'));
            })->when('reorder' === $request->input('filter'),  function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('min_stock', '>', 0);
            });
        })->get();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Help!!!. I have used this code and its throwing an error "Undefined variable: request". I am unable to understand because i have not use this method before.

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer and dont forget to `use use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;`